# Will SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() prompt after user has already given a rating or review?

Tags: ios

I have seen numerous posts explaining the behavior of **SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()**.  All reference Apple's documentation which states that the prompt may or may not be shown, as per "store policy."   I also understand why the call does not return a status indicating whether or not the prompt has been displayed or whether or not the user has given a review -- Apple doesn't want developers rewarding users for a review.

But I have not seen anything which answers this one question.    Namely, will the prompt be displayed if the user has already given a rating or review?    I do not want to harass my users who have already given a review and would love to know if the "store policy" includes not presenting the prompt after a user has already provided a review.    If I can't get this assurance I will program my app to only make a single request ever for each user.   (Or more accurately, for each user's installation on a device.)

If anyone knows where the "store policy" is documented, that would help answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this documentation of how you ask user for rate your app. Below is appstore documentation link for guidelines.

[Aoostore Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/#:%7E:text=Users%20can%20rate%20your%20app,new%20version%20of%20your%20app.)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this does not answer my question. I want to know if the user will see a prompt when I call requestReview() after they have already provided a review or rating.

Comment: If they have already review or rating your prompt will not display for asking review or rating.

Comment: That's good to know. Thank you, Virani.  May I ask if your answer is based on your experience with this function or on any documentation you've seen?